# Help using an attiny85 and ir receiver

Tags: infrared, attiny, ir-receiver

I'm trying to use 2 attiny85, one with an IR transmitter and one with an IR receiver (2 pins). I can't figure out how to use the attiny85 with the receiver. Help would be appreciated! If it is not possible to do it with a 2 pin IR receiver, advice for a 3 pin one would be fine too. Basically, I'm trying to let the attiny85 with the receiver do something when it senses the one with the transmitter is on. Thank you.

Comment: So basically you are asking us to design your system for you? Forget 2-pin receivers (IR fotodiodes?), take a 3-pin one. And you'd better read up on IR protocols, and the datasheet of your receiver. You can't make a reliable IR connection unless you at least obey the basic requirements (frequency, gaps) that the IR receiver requires. If after that you have any specific questions, coma and ask!

Comment: sorry bout that im completely new at this. Ill go read up now.

Comment: Ah, that sets you apart from the ones taks ask 'design my system for me, right know'. Don't hesitate to ask when you have a *specific* question. And use the search on this site, there are probably a few questions/answers that can help you.

Comment: After reading up I think I'm completely lost. I'll just use visible light and an LDR instead. Thanks! :)

Comment: This probably won't work either, unless there's either no ambient light or you know how to modulate it to avoid the effects it'll cause.

Comment: What distance are you trying to achieve, 1cm? 10m? And under what (ambient light) circumstances?

Comment: probably about 2 inches. It would be under indoor lighting. I'm trying to create a robot swarm that communicates with IR.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few Ir receiver/transmitter projects using Attiny85's and Arduino's that you can read through for some info:

http://nathan.chantrell.net/20121014/tinypcremote-an-attiny85-based-infrared-pc-remote-control/

http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/07/09/building-the-phototrap-part-5-the-long-range-infra-red-beam-sensor/

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,10555.0.html

http://tech.x4343.org/posts/2013/08/pulsed-infrared-sender-receiver-with-attiny85/